# AngularJS ng-class and ng-style working together

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat in my div:

```
<div ng-repeat="el in list">
    <button 
     ng-class="{ 'selected' : selectedButton == $index }" 
     ng-style="{ 'background-color' : userColor }"
     >
       {{el}}
    </button>
</div>
```

in css file:

```
.selected{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Idea is to set background color red to button which was lastly pressed. And all other buttons should have background color which user has been selected previously.

Problem is that when background color in ng-style is already applied it won't override it with selected class background-color. I must use selectedButton == $index because other things depend on it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using !important in your class. This might fix your problem.

```
.selected{
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

Inline style has higher precedence over css from class until !important is applied.

Cheers from [CheezyCode](http://www.cheezycode.com)